# Prevent two save calls on cell edit when I enter for save

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Two time call on save cell url in jqgrid (one in case of enter which is default behavior of jqgrid) other is custom save on focusout.

I need to prevent two save calls on cell edit when I enter for save.

```js
column.editoptions.dataEvents = [{
  type: 'keyup focusout',
  fn: function(e) {
    var isValidate = ValidateGridEmail($(this).val());
    EmailValidationMessage(isValidate);
    if (e.type == "focusout" && isValidate && globalVar.irow != null && globalVar.icol != null) {
      $("#GridEditConfiguration").saveCell(globalVar.irow, globalVar.icol);

      globalVar.irow = null;
      globalVar.icol = null;
    }
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some events to do this, but I'm not sure that free-jqGrtid has these. This is not supported version.

In the supported [Guriddo jqGrid](http://guriddo.net/) you can use beforeSaveCell to signal the start of saving and then use this in your condition. Set signal in afterSubmitCell back to false.

Like this:

```
var savestart = false;   
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
    beforeSubmitCell : function( id, name, val, irow,icol) {
        savestart = true;
    },
    afterSubmitCell : function() {
        savestart = false; 
        return [true,""];
    },
    ....
 });
```

in your code add this

```
if (e.type == "focusout" && isValidate && globalVar.irow != null && globalVar.icol != null && !savestart) {
  $("#GridEditConfiguration").saveCell(globalVar.irow, globalVar.icol);
  ...
}
```

Again you should check if these events are available in free-jqGrid